# Section text in User Profile view in Community

Tags: community, page-layout

I have a User profile page layout with sections.  I have section labels that are visible in internal Salesforce.  However, when the user's profile is viewed via the Community, the section labels are not showing.  Any way to make them show?  I don't see another question related to this.

Comment: @DavidCheng  The link you provided seems to take me back to my same question.  Can you resend the link to a solution?

Comment: That was an auto-comment because I voted to close this question as a duplicate of the one in link.